# Oracle - select max from one set, if set is empty then from another set

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
personid INT,
takeid INT,
score INT
```

For every person the takeid can take both negative and positive values. I need a query which:

1) When there is at least one positive takeid for a given person, take max(score) from the set of positive takeid's

2) When all takeid's are negative, select max(score) for given person

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I need the takeid which has the highest score.

Comment: Do you want to see the takeid as well as the person and score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another option using `COALESCE` that looks to see if any takeid's are greater than 0, and if so, to use the max of those.  Else, just use the max(score).

```
select personid, 
  coalesce(max(case when takeid > 0 then score end),max(score)) maxScore
from yourtable
group by personid
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c3be/5)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select personid, 
       case sign(max(takeid))
            when 1 then max(case sign(takeid) when 1 then score)
            else max(score)
       end as maxscore
from scoretable
group by personid
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select personid, max(score) keep (dense_rank last order by sign(takeid) asc) 
  from scoretable
 group by personid
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also be solved with NVL and subselects:

```
select NVL((select max(score) from scoretable t1 where t1.personid = :personid and takeid > 0),
           (select max(score) from scoretable t2 where t2.personid = :personid)
  from scoretable
 group by personid;
```